Revert of the Riesz rearrangement inequality
It is well known from the Riesz rearrangement inequality that
$$
\iint f(x)g(x-y)h(y) \leq \iint f^*(x)g(x-y)h^*(y)
$$
if $g$ is radially symmetric decreasing.
I am wondering if we have the revert inequality of the above if $g$ is radially symmetric increasing?.
